# Replace standalone string with regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I am trying to write a function to replace any standalone set of matching characters. For example:

```js
var myarray = ["this is", "this is iss"]
var my2array = []
var regex = '/bis/b'

for (const i of myarray) {
  var x = i.replace(regex, "")
  my2array.push(x)
}

console.log(my2array)
```

My desired output would be:

```
["this", "this iss"]
```

I got this working in Python, but am not able to translate it properly to Javascript. Currently my output is just the array values `[0]` and `[1]` (not sure why Javascript is doing that).

Anyway, my question is, how can I achieve the desired output using regex in Javascript?

Comment: You're iterating over the array indexes, not the array values.

Comment: My mistake, fixed that (edited). The main problem persists.

Comment: None of your strings contain `bis`, why do you expect it to replace anything?

Comment: should be `var regex = /\bis\b/` you have mistyped slashes.

Comment: The /b is a regex operator to test for a space, correct?

Comment: No, regexp escape sequences begin with backslash, not slash. `/` is the delimiters at the beginning and end of the regexp.

Comment: @find_all No, `\b` is (and it's not just spaces). Maybe a regex tutorial or reference site would be useful. https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: `\b` is a word boundary, not a symbol at all.

Comment: I see now, for some strange reason this worked fine in Python. I will educate myself more on this topic. Maybe I just got lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@benvc's answer is close but leaves extra spaces after replacements, and therefore does not match the desired output.

You can instead use an alternation of two patterns, one that deals with scenarios with spaces on both sides of `is` (in which case you can use a positive lookahead pattern to avoid matching the last space to allow leaving a space between words after replacement), and the other that deals with scenarios with spaces on only one side of `is`, or none at all:

```js
var myarray = ["this is", "this is iss", "is this", "is"]
var my2array = []
var regex = /\s+is\s*(?=\s)|\s*\bis\b\s*/

for (const i of myarray) {
  var x = i.replace(regex, "")
  my2array.push(x)
}

console.log(my2array)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding the regex syntax (forward slashes indicate the start and end of the expression, backslashes are used with various characters to indicate certain character sets). You could replace your regex with the following since I think you intended your regex to replace instances of "is" with [word boundaries](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary) on either side:

```
var regex = /\bis\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not the solution but a working example:

```js
var myarray = ["this is", "this is iss"];
var my2array = [];
var regex = /is/g;

for (const i in myarray) {
  var x = myarray[i].replace(regex, "")
  my2array.push(x)
}

console.log(my2array)
```

Comment: Getting this: Error: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: @find_all This answer was written before you changed `in` to `of`.

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output, because you're not matching word boundaries.

Comment: yup just giving a working example of the use of regex here

Comment: Thanks for this, although this is the output I was getting before, using replace without regex. Barmar is correct in that I am specifically looking looking for standalone strings to be replaced.